# Maximum Err.Raise number?

Tags: vb6, error-handling

Why is it when I use `Err.Raise 65536` the `Err.Number` will actually have the value of 5 and not 65536?

According to `Raise` definition: `Sub Raise(Number As Long, [Source], [Description], [HelpFile], [HelpContext])`. The passing parameter is `Long` and `Err.Number` is also `Long`.

So why can't I use values greater then 65535?

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim a As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrCatch
    For a = 0 To 99999
        Err.Raise a
        DoEvents
    Next a
    Exit Sub
ErrCatch:
    ' this is where Err.Number is evaluated
    Resume Next
End Sub`
```

Comment: It's like poker, you raise by 65536 and vb6 re-raises you by 5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265359(v=vs.60).aspx)

> *Number*
>
> Required. Long integer that identifies the nature of the error. **Visual Basic errors are in the range 0–65535**; the range 0–512 is reserved for system errors; **the range 513–65535 is available for user-defined errors**. When setting the Number property to your own error code in a class module, you add your error code number to the vbObjectError constant. For example, to generate the error number 513, assign vbObjectError + 513 to the Number property.

So even though you can submit a value larger than 65535, anything larger than 65535 will become Error 5.

Comment: Whilst the document tells you to add vbObjectError to the error value you want to pass, it would be technically more correct to OR this value with vbObjectError, since the latter is part of a 32-bit bitfield.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw: If it's a bit field, then ORing or adding would be equally correct.

Comment: -1, this does not seem correct to me. The error does not "become" 5, you're actually introducing a new error, as per Omar Jackman's answer.

Comment: @AndréNeves - which is exactly what I meant, and almost exactly what I said; would it be better if I said "will become a *new* Error 5"?  You're being pretty nitpicky there, but whatever, thanks for the downvote.  I noticed I got downvoted on a lot of other stuff as well around the same time, sure hope you didn't go through the rest of my questions serially downvote me...

Comment: Sorry for the other downvotes. I can assure you I didn't stalk you. This wording isn't precise either, because nothing *becomes* something else; the error handling function **has a bug**. *Even though you can submit a value larger than 65535* — well, turns out you *can't*, and that's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 10):

There is a further level beyond "Microsoft said so". The error number that you raise is a 32-bit integer because this is part of the COM specification for passing errors between components. All public methods of a component are actually functions returning the HRESULT as the return value; if you have a VB function, it secretly maps the return value of the function to an [out] parameter. The HRESULT value is a bitfield comprised of a whole heap of values; but to keep things simple, you can divide it into two 16-bit portions. The lower 16 bits contain the actual error number, which happen to be between 0 and 65535 - the unsigned 16 bit range. There are many standards for the upper 16 bits. The most important is 0x0000____. All constants using this start with "S_" (stands for success). The most common used 32bit value is S_OK (0x00000000). If this value is returned, then the function has succeeded. Most of your VB method calls will return this value. Any value whose top bit is set, however, indicates that there has been an error. In hex, these are values looking like 0x8___ . There are many classes of error. The one which VB returns by default is 0x800A. However, the COM specification only gives you one class you can officially use, 0x8004 - which is represented in VB as the constant vbObjectError.

In fact, VB recommends you use the vbObjectError constant when raising errors on public methods in ActiveX DLLs or EXEs. Whether you do or not makes no difference. It just means that the error that is received by the calling code is very large and negative, so you will have to AND your error number with &H0000FFFF to get your 16 bit integer back. Interestingly, it also recommends that you *don't* do this with ActiveX control methods, probably because the upper 16 bits associated with ActiveX control methods is 0x800A000. Even more interestingly, VB itself ANDs all error numbers with 0x800A0000 when you raise them by default. Likewise it detects whether an error number is like 0x800A____ - and if so, removes the upper 16 bits for you, anyway, so you just deal with the error number itself. At my workplace, we have many VB components. Our standard is to not OR the error code with vbObjectError. This saves us the bother of subsequently having to mask it out in the calling code.

For instance, if you have COMPONENT1.CLASS1 and COMPONENT2.CLASS2. CLASS1.Method1 calls CLASS2.Method1. If I raise an error in CLASS2, then I must handle it in CLASS1.Method1. Following Microsoft's dictates, I would write it like this:

COMPONENT1.CLASS1

```
Function Method1()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ...
ErrorHandler:
    If (Err.Number And vbObjectError) = vbObjectError Then
        Select Case Err.Number And (Not vbObjectError)
        Case Component2.EErrComponent2.ecBlahBlahError
            ... handle ...
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

COMPONENT2.CLASS2

```
Enum EErrComponent2
    ecBlahBlahError = 513 ' Minimum error code
End Enum

Function Method1()
...
    Err.Raise EErrComponent1 Or vbObjectError
...
End Function
```

Repeat this for multiple components, this boilerplate gets a little tiresome, and doesn't seem to actually give us anything in return.

We would probably do this:

COMPONENT1.CLASS1

```
Function Method1()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ...
ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Component2.EErrComponent2.ecBlahBlahError
        ... handle ...
    End Select
End Function
```

COMPONENT2.CLASS2
Enum EErrComponent2
ecBlahBlahError
End Enum

```
Function Method1()
...
    Err.Raise EErrComponent1
...
End Function
```

I wonder if anyone has ever had problems when not using vbObjectError. We certainly haven't.

Comment: I don't use `vbObjectError` and don't have issues as long as I avoid the reserved range.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for all along. I've linked to it in a comment on a [CodeReview.SE answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64756/23788) that might interest you... if you're still into VB :)

Comment: "ignore vbObjectError to take advantage of this behaviour." - I need to see some code to understand what that means.

Comment: I suspect everyone is wrong who says vbObjectError prevents overlap between native and user-defined exceptions. If that were true, it wouldn't force the developer to start their error-numbering at 513. vbObjectError would start 513 numbers higher. But 0-513 is exposed. Nothing stops me from writing "MyError = vbObjectError + 0". But instead, i have to memorize the arbitrary number 513. It seems clear that the purpose of vbObjectError is to transform Err.Num's to shorter, non-negative, human-friendly numbers. However, i'm still learning about vbObjectError and i may be totally wrong!

Comment: @johnywhy I suppose it is possible that Microsoft itself might have written code which only looks at the bottom 16 bits to get the error code, and they reserved 0-512 for their own error code.

Answer (score 9):

error 5 is

```
Run-Time Error '5': Invalid Procedure Call or Argument”
```

Along with Justins answer this would make sense. The Raise function is throwing error 5 when you call it with an integer more than 65535 because it is an invalid argument.

Can you please show some code and I can help you a little better?

Answer (score 0):

Although `Number` is specified as a `Long`, in the documentation for `Err.Raise` it says that only values 0-65535 are valid.  Thus, the error you are seeing is actually because you are violating the constraints on `Err.Raise`.

Why they didn't make it an `Integer` is a mystery (perhaps in case the valid range is expanded in the future).

Comment: My guess is because the maximum `Integer` size in VB6 is 32767.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables That's a signed int - unsigned would be ~twice that

Comment: VB6 has no unsigned integer type of any length, except Byte.

Comment: Not to mention that `Err.Raise` allows negative numbers for `Number`.